# Doctrine problems with the schema:update when using an array type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am using the following orm description:

```
App\Entity\Journal:
type: entity
table: hpa_journal
repositoryClass: App\Repository\JournalRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    longDescription:
        type: array
        nullable: true
        column: long_description
```

When I run a `doctrine:schema:create` it has no problems at all and creates the DB.
But, when I run a `schema:update` I get the following error:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

 The following SQL statements will be executed:
     ALTER TABLE HPA_JOURNAL MODIFY (long_description CLOB DEFAULT NULL);
```

Which makes no sense since the `CLOB` is already as `DEFAULT NULL`, doctrine made it that way with the `schema:create`

When I run the `schema:update --force` to get rid of the message, I get the ORACLE error:

```
ORA-22859: invalid modification of columns
```

Answer (score 0):

When doctrine compares the DB and the model it triggers a problem since in the DB the types "text", "array", "json_array",... are just CLOBS.
In order to really make the difference you must add (if not made automatically like in my case) a proper comment:

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN HPA_JOURNAL.LONG_DESCRIPTION IS '(DC2Type:array)'
```